# Joomla JText translation in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, translation

I'm porting a small web app (PHP + Javascript) running in a JUMI element from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5.

Basically in 1.5 for translation we used jsJText to make the translated strings available in Javascript. From what I understood in several tutorials, 2.5 should make this easier since support for translation in Javascript is integrated.

After checking several sites and google results they all pretty much say: First add your strings to the javascript language store in PHP by using JText::script('key'); and later retrieve them in javascript using Joomla.JText._('key') or Joomla.JText.strings.key.

I'm having quite a bit of trouble getting this to work however. Translations in PHP work perfectly fine, but in Javascript I end up getting undefined instead of the correct translated text.

I've taken a small screenshot illustrating my approach and the problem.
[image]

The PHP file containing the language strings is included into the main PHP page which shows the content. This is pretty much the first include in the page.

I'm pretty sure I've made a stupid mistake somewhere, but honestly can't find it for the life of me. Anyone that can point me in the right direction of where to search would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

20130612-Edit:

A little more info on the stuff I've tried suggested in the comments:

- Enabling joomla debuggin didn't help. No errors there.
- Mootools is loaded, version 1.4.5.

I've also tried something a little unorthodox. The list of JText::script lines are in a separate PHP file. I've tried including that file into a random module and showing that module on the same page as my web app. At that point it did work. However, this isn't really a solution to the problem but just a rather dirty workaround.

That test does however confirm there's no real problem with the code itself. I'm just missing something somewhere. Still stumped as to what's missing. Any pointers on what it could be?

20130612-Edit2:

I've compared the page source when the include is in a random module, and when it's in my webapp. The only difference seems to be that the following Javascript is added to the page, which I believe should be generated by the JText::script code so... I'm really stumped.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        var strings = {"PA_ITEM_BLOWD":"Blow-dryer"...};
        if (typeof Joomla == 'undefined') {
          Joomla = {};
          Joomla.JText = strings;
        }
        else {
          Joomla.JText.load(strings);
        }
      })();
    </script>
```

Comment: `<script>alert('<?= JText::_('PA_ITEM_COMPU') ?>');</script>`

Comment: That's using PHP in javascript, in this example this would work. This was just an example to illustrate the problem though. In the web app I'm using dynamic keys which need to be translated.

Comment: Try turning on Joomla debugging and see what comes out

Comment: The strings didn't load: try `Joomla.JText._('PA_ITEM_COMPU', 'string missing');`, but I have no idea why as you say these works sever-side. What if you'd try an alert after DOM is ready? `window.addEvent('domready', function() { alert( Joomla.JText._('PA_ITEM_COMPU')) });`

Comment: make sure you have mootools loaded on your site aswell as this is a mootools function

Comment: @Lodder Mootools is loaded, version 1.4.5. Will try turning on Joomla debugging next. I've tried using firebug's console to alert the item after the page is loaded, this gives the same undefined.

Comment: We never really fixed this. We worked around it by including the PHP file with the JText::Script lines in another module that got loaded on every page. A dirty work-around but at least it allowed our site to go live. Sorry for the late reply, haven't been on stackoverflow lately.